# El hosting no reconoce el CSS

Tags: html, css3

soy un principiante en esto de la programación al subir mi página al hosting no reconoce el css ya e intentado todo lo que este a mi conocimiento limpie los cache y a un sigue el mismo problema cualquier ayuda se los voy agradecer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/fontawesome/css/all.min.css"> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/Logo oficial.png"> <title>Pest control</title> </head>
```

Gracias

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu código?

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué significa que *no lo reconoce*? ¿Da error 404 u otro? Muestra cómo incluyes esos archivos y muestra un árbol de directorios donde podamos ver la ubicación de los archivos que están dando problemas.

Comment: Hola, no da error 404 el problema es que cuando subo la pagina al hosting no me esta reconociendo los estilos que le di con CSS ni el javaScript se ve como en la estructura de html le con parto el link de la pagina www.melext.com para que lo puedan visualizar.

Comment: Es problema de rutas. Clic derecho > Ver código fuente > clic en el CSS. Nada de lo que estas llamando tiene la ruta correcta. **No has puesto nada de código**, si no lo haces van a terminar cerrando la pregunta.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/Logo oficial.png">
    <title>Pest control</title>
</head>

Comment: Hola Mel, bienvenido, para obtener una buena respuesta, es imprescindible formular una buena pregunta, esto implica, explicar claramente el problema, y adjuntar los códigos involucrados y los mensajes de error (si los huiera) ambos en formato texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio,